# Format the table output from 'Show Detail' on a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, excel-drilldown

I am using Excel 2016, and pivot tables.

When I use the 'Show Detail' function or double click a value form the pivot table, I get the drill down of the data.

However it is always in a basic format.

Can this be set to a customized format ?

[image]